# Loading one Google Script inside of another

Tags: google-apps-script

How do you load/include a Google Script inside another script in the same Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! You don't have to, all scripts in a project are loaded when any function is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Script Libraries. Write a script and publish a version of it. In the second script, you can access functions of the first, by adding it as a library in Resources --> Manage Libraries.

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) for full details on creating and accessing a library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I was just looking to re-use the scripts within their own project. Turns out that happens automatically..